# Any solution to "Publisher Action disappears when switching between Salesforce console tabs"?

Tags: visualforce, service-cloud-console, publisher-action

In my Salesforce developer org, I have created an app `Foo1` that uses the console and displays Accounts and Contacts.

I have created a Publisher Action called `FooAction`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QuickAction xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <height>250</height>
    <label>FooAction</label>
    <page>Foo</page>
    <type>VisualforcePage</type>
    <width>-100</width>
</QuickAction>
```

I have created a Visualforce page `Foo`:

```
<apex:page >
    Foo
</apex:page>
```

I have added the action as a quick action on both the Contact and Account layouts:

```
...
<quickActionList>
    <quickActionListItems>
        <quickActionName>FooAction</quickActionName>
    </quickActionListItems>
...
```

It looks like this:

[image]

In both Firefox 30.0 and IE 11 when I open 2 or more Accounts into Salesforce console tabs, when I switch between the tabs the contents of the `FooAction` Publisher Action are empty.

It then looks like this:

[image]

In Firefox attempting to refresh the Publisher Action iframe has no effect.

In IE attempting to refresh the Publisher Action iframe produces this message:

[image]

This is a bummer.

Can a mere developer make this work?